# Stream video htmlPy

Tags: javascript, python, multithreading, video, video-streaming

I'm using [htmlPy](https://github.com/amol-mandhane/htmlPy) to build a python standalone app. What I'm trying to achieve is to get something like an iFrame containing a video. The video should be what the webcam is recording in the moment. What I've achieved for the moment is to get the video using cv2, and trying to update the "div" with a JPG, and repeat this process constantly.

The problem I'm having is that using htmlPy when I try to process this, it's done in the main thread, blocking the whole application. When I try creating a new one, the new thread does not have access to the GUI (using javascript, I can't even do a console.log on the new thread), failing to update the GUI correctly.

The code I have to gather the information and try to update the HTML is the following:

```
class Camera(htmlPy.Object):

  def __init__(self,app):
    super(Camera,self).__init__()
    self.app = app
    return

  @htmlPy.Slot()
  def send_image_to_html(self,jpeg):
    b64 = base64.encodestring(jpeg)
    generatedImage = "<html><img src='data:image/png;base64,"+b64 +"'></html>"
    #js_to_eval = "$('#camera-div').html("+generatedImage+");}";
    js_to_eval = "console.log('Hello from new thread')"
    print("Eval: "+js_to_eval)
    self.app.evaluate_javascript(js_to_eval)  

  def setup_camera(self):
    vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
        rval, frame = vc.read()
    else:
        rval = False

    while rval:
        time.sleep(2)
        jpeg = cv2.imencode('.png', frame)[1]
        self.send_image_to_html(jpeg)
        rval, frame = vc.read()
        #key = cv2.waitKey(20)
        #if key == 27: # exit on ESC
        #    break


  @htmlPy.Slot()
  def start_camera(self):
    self.setup_camera()
    self.app.evaluate_javascript("console.log('Hello from back-end')")
```

As you might've guessed, I can only see the "Hello from back-end" console.logs, but I can't see the "Hello from new thread".

I was wondering if there's any workaround to update the GUI using Javascript, Jinja2 (htmlPy uses jinja2), or even flash. The idea is that this small App runs on a raspberry Pi, so I'm trying to keep things as simple as possible.

Regards